# Python: list function and lambda expressions

Tags: python, function, lambda, reduce

So I need to make a function that sums the squares of the numbers up until n, using only a return.

I've tried:

```
    from functools import reduce

    def soma_quadrados(n):
        return sum(list(reduce(lambda x: x**2, list(range(1,n+1)))))
```

Which gives the error:`lambda () takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

I've also tried

```
    return sum(list(reduce(lambda x: x**2, n)))
```

Which gives the error: `reduce() arg 2 must support iteration`

What should I do?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you think you need `reduce` at all?

Comment: @bereal it's also demanded, forgot to mention that. Either reduce, filter or map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reduce()` passes in two arguments: the result accumulated so far, and the next value. Your `lambda` doesn't accept the result argument (the first).

If you want to produce a sum of all the squares, use `sum()` with a generator expression:

```
sum(i ** 2 for i in range(1, n + 1))
```

or use `map()` to map integers to their square in place of the generator expression:

```
sum(map(lambda i: i ** 2, range(1, n + 1)))
```

If you *must* use `reduce()`, have it sum:

```
reduce(lambda r, i: r + i ** 2, range(1, n + 1), 0)
```